# How can I design a Django Model with existing rows in one of the column?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a challenge with designing Django model that has existing rows in one of the column as shown below:-

| Gaming device in use | Gaming Tax on GGR | Tax Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No of shop/places |  |  |
| No of slot machines |  |  |
| Total Value |  |  |

I have tried to create one Model with column attributes as fields but I don't figure out how to put number of shops/places and number of slot machines in my Model.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the column types and create a model class with the same column name and types.
2. Run the python manage.py makemigrations
3. Run the python manage.py migrate
4. Add new columns (number_of_shops and number_of_slot_machines)
5. Run the python manage.py makemigrations
6. Run the python manage.py migrate

Comment: As I understand you are trying the setup relation between models. This relation is "many_to_many" or foreign key relation. did you check the relations? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I come up with the following;                                               `class FortyMachineSite(GamingDeviceInUse):                                                                               
device_in_use = models.CharField(max_length = 50) ,gross_gaming_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  number_of_shops = models.PositiveIntegerField() number_of_slot_machines = models.PositiveIntegerField()                                            tax_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)`

Comment: Regardless of relations, what I'm trying to achieve is how do I put number_of _places and number_of_slot_machines in a Model? I tried to create two different models - one named GamingDeviceInUse with those two fields, another one containing the other columns. I don't know if I' correct.

Comment: number_of_slot_machines = models.ManyToManyField(GamingDeviceInUse)
with this way, you can create a relation. or we misunderstand each other :) If this is not answer your question, please create an image and show me the what do you want.